# inject() must be called from an injection context Angular Nx

Tags: angular, nomachine-nx

update version 14 to 16
Nx app route not working
Error: NG0203: inject() must be called from an injection context such as a constructor, a factory function, a field initializer, or a function used with

update version 14 to 16
Nx app route not working

Comment: could you provide a callstack and piece of code where this is happening?

Comment: I'm facing an issue when running multiple apps simultaneously. When I run a single app at a time, everything works fine without any errors. However, when I attempt to host two or more apps concurrently, I encounter an error, and I'm having difficulty pinpointing the source of the problem. I'm looking for assistance in diagnosing and resolving this issue. Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: right, but when you see an error it most likely has a callstack associated with it. could you provide it?

Answer (score 0):

`NG0203` typically happens when you have more than 1 instance of `@angular/core` in your app.

run `npm ls @angular/core` to see this and find the culprit.

Comment: still its not working 
we have used angular nx module federation